# Reloading a dynamically loaded script

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom, mathjax

I am loading the mathJax javascript library over their CDN dynamically [their CDN dynamically](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/dynamic.html).  This is so I can apply it to a html partial page I am loading at the same time.

As it stands, the scripts will load once but not reload when the html partial page changes.  I have tried using a timestamp on the CDN URL and removing the scripts from the DOM, among other things.  I have been trying to solve this all afternoon with no success.  There are no errors appearing.

So, is there anything else I can try to get the scripts to reload with each new html snippet?  Thanks a ton for any suggestions.  Here is my code:

```
$scope.getLesson = function (x)
{
    $scope.lessonMenu = false;
    $scope.hiddenMenuLink = true;
    x = x.replace(/[\s]/g, '');
    $scope.parse = $parse(x)($scope);                
    var i = 0;

    $.get("Lessons/" + x + ".html", function (data) {

        // send the current html to view
        $scope.currentLessonHTML = data.toString();

        // destroy mathjax if existing
        if (i > 1 && script1.parentNode != null) {
            script1.parentNode.removeChild(script1);
            script2.parentNode.removeChild(script2);
            i = 0;
        }    

        // loading the MathJax dynamically
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        var script1 = document.createElement("script");
        var script2 = document.createElement("script");
        var responsibleSibling = document.createElement("script");

        var mathJax = "http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" + "?nocache=" + new Date().getTime();
        var mathJaxConfig = 'MathJax.Hub.Config({extensions: ["tex2jax.js"], jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],tex2jax: {inlineMath: [ ["$","$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ],displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[","\\]"] ],processEscapes: true},"HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }});';
        script1.type = "text/x-mathjax-config";
        script1[(window.opera ? "innerHTML" : "text")] = mathJaxConfig;                
        head.appendChild(script1);
        script2.type = "text/javascript";
        script2.src = mathJax;
        head.appendChild(script2);
        i++;

        // apply new lesson
        $scope.showLesson = true;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
}
```

Comment: Removing a script tag, doesn't remove the corresponding JavaScript objects/functions/variables with it. The script tags are evaluated into the global object. So reloading a script is kind of a bad idea IMO. Also why do you want to reload a script. Their script isn't changing. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Mouser , Yeah, that makes sense.  Thank you.  Do you know if there is a way to replace the scripts within the global object, or call them from the object?

Comment: You can change every object dynamically that is in the global object (global = window)

Comment: @Mouser So,along those lines, do you think if I loaded the scripts elsewhere with an ID tag, I could call them in my function by their ID?

Comment: I'm not quite getting you. If said `bogus.js` loads function `a` and you would load `other.js` that also has a function `a`, the latter will overwrite the former. Because bogus gets evaluated into the window object as `window.a`. When other is evaluated, JavaScript sees that window.a exists, and overwrites it with the other `a` function. So you can't set two functions `a` by loading them in a different tag with different ids.

Comment: Okay.  I'll spend a bit more time reading up on JS and the DOM and see if I can come to anything.  Thanks a million for your feedback,

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out.  The script was being reloaded, but it was not applying the typeset specific to the Mathjax library.  The solution is a built-in function to queue the typeset to async operations, like such:

MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);

http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html

Thanks for feedback.